# How to pass multiple items for onselect event for ng-multiselect-dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I have a multi-select drop-down with many items to select. As of now When I select single item, the item is passed to `Onselect` event and based on condition the respective data from another array `newArrayAfterProjectFilter` is pushed to`myDataList` as shown below in `OnselectErp`. As per my requirement When I try to select 2nd item in dropdown, only the 2nd item is pushed to `OnselectErp`function, not both items(1st and 2nd).

How to correctly do this?

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown *ngIf="showDropDown"
 [placeholder]="'Erp Rfq Number'" [data]="dropdown_Erp"
 [settings]="dropdownSettings" (onSelect)="OnselectErp($event)">
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

```
OnselectErp(item: any) {
    this.myDataList = [];
    this.newArrayAfterProjectFilter.forEach(element => {
      if (element.properties.map.aclrq_rfqNum == item.item_text) {
        this.myDataList.push(element);
      }
    });
    console.log(this.myDataList)
  }
```

Comment: i am still unable to understand your requirement. can you please explain with little bit more detail.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but wouldn't the type of the item parameter be an array in that case? Single select would give you an `item:YourItemType` whereas multiselect should yield `item:Array<MyItemType>`.

Comment: What you want is to filter your table after you have finished selecting multiple items.`(onSelect)` will fire each time you select an item so it will not serve your purpose. One solution is to have a button. On click of button you first read all selected items and then filter the table.

Comment: @gkulshrestha. You are clearly understood what i need. can you answer this by taking a example or taking my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would need more details to reproduce your issue and provide you complete solution.
But you can try below:

Add `[(ngModel)]="selectedItems"` in HTML and add `selectedItems` property in corresponding component.ts

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown *ngIf="showDropDown"
 [placeholder]="'Erp Rfq Number'" [data]="dropdown_Erp"
 [settings]="dropdownSettings" (onSelect)="OnselectErp($event)" 
 [(ngModel)]="selectedItems">
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Create a button on UI and on click call below function:

```
filter() {
     this.myDataList = this.newArrayAfterProjectFilter.filter(element => 
      this.selectedItems.some(item=> element.properties.map.aclrq_rfqNum == item.item_text));
    console.log(this.myDataList)
  }
```

As I said, I have not tried this but should work with no or minimal change.

Comment: Thank you for this, I implemented multi select without a button needed following your code.

Comment: Great! What approach you took?

Comment: Used NgModel that's it. Didn't use it before. We don't need button for ng-multiselect-dropdown.

Comment: That means,`OnselectErp` is being called on each `select` and list is being filtered each time too. I would rather let user first finish the selection and then trigger a filter (via a button) . Your design is also OK as long as there are not too many records to filter otherwise its not efficient.

Comment: yes you absolutely right here. I'll try to make it more efficient in future. As of now it is sufficient and fast enough for me.

Comment: You can upvote this answer and/or accept it as answer. This way it will be helpful for anyone who has similar issue.